# trying to find an Element on DOM with typescript

Tags: angularjs, typescript, selector, element

I m totally newbie in typescript. I m just trying to find an element with a selector. whatever i tried findElement() method is always turning undefined. Where am i doing wrong ?
Any help greatly appreciated !

```
var cdnBasePath: any = this.findElement('meta[name="cdnBasePath"]').attr('content');

public findElement(selector: any) {

            if (angular.isDefined(this.$window.jQuery)) {
                return this.$document.find(selector);
            } else {
                return angular.element(this.$document.querySelector(selector));
            }

        }
```

Comment: Try to trace JavaScript execution in Firefox/Chrome console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for "this" to be defined you have to declare your findElement as a instance method of some class. Like this:

```
class SomeClass
{
    public SomeMethod() 
    {
        var cdnBasePath: any = this.findElement('meta[name="cdnBasePath"]').attr('content');
    }

    public findElement(selector: any) 
    {
        if (angular.isDefined(this.$window.jQuery)) {
            return this.$document.find(selector);
        } else {
            return angular.element(this.$document.querySelector(selector));
        }
    }
}
```

Otherwise you can have it as static method:

```
class UI
{
    public static findElement(selector: any) 
    {
            if (angular.isDefined(this.$window.jQuery)) {
                return this.$document.find(selector);
            } else {
                return angular.element(this.$document.querySelector(selector));
            }
    }
}

var cdnBasePath: any = UI.findElement('meta[name="cdnBasePath"]').attr('content');
```

Or just drop 'this' and have it as global function (I do not recommend this)

```
function findElement(selector: any) 
{
    if (angular.isDefined(this.$window.jQuery)) {
        return this.$document.find(selector);
    } else {
        return angular.element(this.$document.querySelector(selector));
    }
}

var cdnBasePath: any = findElement('meta[name="cdnBasePath"]').attr('content');
```

Hope this helps.